# What is the difference between these OIDs on a Aruba Wlan Controller?

Tags: switch, snmp, access-point, monitoring, aruba

For my bachelors thesis, I have to monitor the WLAN Access Points of the university campus. For example, number of connected Clients and how many Clients are connected to each Access Point. Therefore I need to find the OIDs on the Aruba WLAN controller.
I went through them with a MIB Browser and found multiple Objects, that cover Clients. I have no idea, which one is actually showing the connected Clients (every device that connects to an Access Point (wireless)):

wlsxUserTable (1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2):
This Table lists all the users (both wired and wireless) currently
connected to the controller.

wlsxSwitchStationMgmtTable (1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.1.2.2):
This Table lists all the wireless stations associated with the
Access points connected to this switch.

wlsxSwitchUserTable (1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.1.2.1):
This Table lists all the users (both wired and wireless) currently
connected to the switch. Users are identified by their IP address.

wlsxWlanStationTable (1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.5.2.2.1):
This Table lists all the wireless stations associated with the
Access points connected to this controller.

Does anyone have any idea, what the different objects represent and what the differences between them could be?

I really don't understand which table is relevant for me and I have no idea how to find out. My prof couldn't really help me out. He assumes each one of them is relevant, but I'm not sure about that.

The tables are pretty similar. They list the Users and informations about them, although the informations that are available differ:

[image: wlsxUserTable]

[image: wlsxSwitchStationMgmtTable]

[image: wlsxSwitchUserTable]

[image: wlsxWlanStationTable]

Comment: Ultimately, we need more context. All of these could be useful depending upon what problem you're trying to solve. Can you tell us more about what your desired outcome is?

Comment: I need to make a website, that shows information about the wireless APs on the university campus:
- how many people connect with the wifi at our university in total (per day,week,month)
- for each AP individually: how many people are connected

and more information f.ex. how many persons are students/guests/... depending on vlan.


I need to extract all user and AP info from the oids of the controller and then save them in a DB. Now I wonder, f.ex. if the users that are "currently connected to the switch" also need to be saved, or if this is irrelevant for me.

Comment: I don't really have any more information, I can share, because obviously I can't share the output. But it seems like nobody knows an answer to this question and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at wlsxWlanAPStatsTable "Access Point Stats entry"

1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.5.3.1.1.1

[image]